# HIVE how to limit number of entries in group

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I'm learning HIVE these days and meet some problems...

I have a table called SAMPLE:

```
USER_ID PRODUCT_ID NUMBER
1       3          20
1       4          30
1       2          25
1       6          50
1       5          40
2       1          10
2       3          15
2       2          40
2       5          30
2       3          35
```

How can I use HIVE to group table by user_id and in each group order the records by DESC order of NUMBER and in each group I want to keep up to 3 records.

The result I want to have is like:

```
USER_ID PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(optional column)
1       6          50
1       5          40
1       4          30
2       2          40
2       3          35
2       5          30

or

USER_ID PRODUCT_IDs 
1       [6,5,4]
2       [2,3,5]
```

Could someone help me ?..
Thanks very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

try this,

```
select user_id,product_id,number
from(
select user_id,product_id,number, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition BY user_id) as RNUM
from (
   select user_id, number,product_id
   from SAMPLE
   order by number desc
) t) t2
where RNUM <=3
```

output

```
1   6   50
1   5   40
1   4   30
2   2   40
2   3   35
2   5   30
```

hive version should be 0.11 or greater, may I know if your version is lower

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are very brilliant, the solution is perfect! Thanks again and I can finish my final project by your solution :)